# Possible types of $_POST and $_GET values

Tags: php, types

**Is it possible for there to by any type of value in `$_GET` or `$_POST` which is *not* an array or string?**

For those who read code better, is it at all possible to run this simple script on a *web server* and get it to throw the exception?

```
// crash-me.php
<?php

function must_be_array_or_string($value) {
    if(is_string($value))
        return;
    if(is_array($value)) {
        foreach($value as $subValue)
            must_be_array_or_string($subValue);
        return;
    }
    throw new Exception("Value is " . gettype($value));
}

if(isset($_GET))
    must_be_array_or_string($_GET);

if(isset($_POST))
    must_be_array_or_string($_POST);
```

Answer (score 7):

Except for file uploads, values are always strings or arrays.

Comment: File uploads are not present in `$_POST` or `$_GET`, you have to check `$_FILES` for information on file uploads (and even then the contents are still arrays and strings).

Comment: @dcousineau: Are you sure? I believe the `error` index in `$_FILES` holds integers, like `UPLOAD_ERR_OK`.

Comment: Is there a source for your answer? And is there any context in which `$_GET[$someKey]` or `$_POST[$someKey]` can result in an array with size < 2?

Answer (score 1):

I believe in the case of file uploads, the `'error'` and `'size'` fields would be `ints`.